# Ocultar y Mostrar Input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel

tengo un listado de usuario (tabla), con los botones de crear usuario y editar usuario. Al crear usuario necesito ocultar el input password, lo logro con mi script:

->crear usuario:

```
 <a href="{{ route('admin.users.create') }}"  id="btn-btn-create" class="btn btn-success pull-right modal-show" style="margin-top: -8px;" title="Crear Ususario"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Crear</a>
```

->script:

```
$('#btn-btn-create').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $("#password").css("display", "none");
    $("#password_confirmation").css("display", "none");     


});
```

editar usuario:

```
<a href="{{ $url_edit }}" class="modal-show edit" id="btn-btn-edit" title="Editar {{ $usuarios->name}}"><i class="fa fa-edit text-success"></i></a>
```

pero al momento de editar mi usuario quiero volver a mostrar el input password
lo intento con esto, lo cual no me esta funcionando:

```
$('#btn-btn-edit').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $("#password").css("display", "block");
    $("#password_confirmation").css("display", "block");        


});
```

este es mi formulario:

```
<div class="row">
{!! Form::model($user, [
    'route' => $user->exists ? ['admin.users.update', $user->id] : 'admin.users.store',   
    'method' => $user->exists ? 'PUT' : 'POST'
]) !!}
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Datos personales</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">                
                <!-- abre formulario -->
                    <div class="form-group">              
                        {!! Form::label('name', 'Nombre') !!}                    
                        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name', 'placeholder' => 'Nombre']) !!}
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('email', 'Email') !!}             
                        {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'email', 'placeholder' => 'Email']) !!}
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" style="display: none;">
                        {!! Form::label('password', 'Contraseña') !!}                                               
                        {!! Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'password', 'placeholder' => 'Contraseña')) !!}        
                        <!-- ver de poder mostrarlo con jquery -->
                        <span class="help-block">Dejar en blanco para no cambiar la contraseña</span>   
                    </div> 

                     <div class="form-group" style="display: none;">
                        {!! Form::label('password_confirmation', 'Repite la Contraseña') !!}                                               
                        {!! Form::password('password_confirmation', array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'password_confirmation', 'placeholder' => 'Repite la Contraseña')) !!}   
                    </div> 
                    <span class="help-block">La contraseña será generada y enviada al nuevo usuario vía email</span>                 
                <!-- cierra formulario -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}    
</div>
```

No comprendo lo que estoy haciendo mal!!

Comment: Hola, para ayudarte sube el código HTML también.

Comment: edite mi pregunta agregando el formulario

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que en tus funciones estas ocultando y mostrando los elementos input cuando lo que deberias ocultar y mostrar son los div, ya que son a estos a los que ocultas al principio:

```
<div class="form-group" style="display: none;">
```

Te recomiendo que les asignes un id a esos divs:

```
<div id="dpassword" class="form-group" style="display: none;">
  {!! Form::label('password', 'Contraseña') !!}                                               
  {!! Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'password', 'placeholder' => 'Contraseña')) !!}        
  <!-- ver de poder mostrarlo con jquery -->
  <span class="help-block">Dejar en blanco para no cambiar la contraseña</span>   
</div> 

<div id="dpassword_confirmation" class="form-group" style="display: none;">
  {!! Form::label('password_confirmation', 'Repite la Contraseña') !!}                                               
  {!! Form::password('password_confirmation', array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'password_confirmation', 'placeholder' => 'Repite la Contraseña')) !!}   
</div>
```

y luego cambies tus funciones jquery así:

```
$('#btn-btn-create').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#dpassword").css("display", "none");
    $("#dpassword_confirmation").css("display", "none");     
});

$('#btn-btn-edit').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#dpassword").css("display", "block");
    $("#dpassword_confirmation").css("display", "block");        
});
```

nombrando a los divs y no a los inputs para ocultar y mostrar tus campos correctamente.

Comment: lo tengo tal cual me lo recomendaste pero no me esta funcionando solo los oculta pero no lo muestra si presiono sobre edit

Comment: he probado en mi local y funciona bien, puedo subir mi ejemplo para que lo veas si aun no te sale.

Comment: no no me esta funcionando #btn-btn-edit le pase un alert no esta entrando . existe alguna otra alternativa??

Comment: puedes ver que error te aparece en la consola? tal vez hay algun error en el javascript